# Control activities instance from one Activity class

Tags: android, android-intent

Please help me this question.
Example I have Activity class MyActivity. I start this Activity and call this instance is "Home". In this activity I have three button. 
called : Button1, Button2, Button3.
When I click on one button, it will start another instance of MyActivity.
So, Could I do like this :

I click on Button1 start A1 , click on Button2 start A2, and then Button3 start A3. We will have activity stack like this : home ->A1 ->A2->A3.
On Activity A3(an instance of MyActivity). When I click on Button1 could I move A1 to front instead of create new one ?
I wonder could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A1, A2 and A3 are all instances of `MyActivity` you cannot do this because there is no way to tell Android which instance of `MyActivity` you want to bring to the front.

However, if you create 3 new activities (`A1`, `A2` and `A3`), each of which derive from `MyActivity`, then you can do this by setting the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` when starting these activities.

You will need to have all 4 activities (`MyActivity`, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`) in the manifest.

You will have something like this:

```
public class A1 extends MyActivity {
}

public class A2 extends MyActivity {
}

public class A3 extends MyActivity {
}
```

and in `MyActivity`, in 'onClick()`when you start an activity (either`A1`,`A2`or`A3`) you do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A1.class); // or A2 or A3
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you. @David Wasser. I have thought about this solution after asked this question. Maybe it is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start a new activity, try to use with you intent this flag

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: The main problem here is : A1, A2, A3 are instance of MyActivity class. So, I can't using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT